# POST request fails on flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm trying to reproduce the code from this [page](https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/#example-code), the complete github code is [here](https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/flask-connexion-rest/version_4):

The application works just fine on the browser, but I'm not able of reproduce the POST request from python.

I have tried with the same data showed on the payload when I use the browser

[image]

```
PEOPLE =  {"fname": "DDoug",
        "lname": "FarDrell"}

url = "http://localhost:5000/api/people"
data = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(PEOPLE) )
```

but I get the following errror:

```
data.text

'{\n  "detail": "Invalid Content-type (), expected JSON data",\n  "status": 415,\n  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}\n'
```

I tried like this as well:

```
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/people"
data = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(PEOPLE) )
```

BUT got this error:

```
'{\n  "detail": "Invalid Content-type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), expected JSON data",\n  "status": 415,\n  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}\n'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `Content-Type` into your post headers to specify you're sending JSON data:

```
requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(PEOPLE), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

You can also use the [`json`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post) parameter to achieve the same result:

```
requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(PEOPLE))
```

Comment: Some examples don"t have that, how do you know is necessary?

Comment: By default the request headers is `None`, so will not be read as JSON. You can also (as a shorthand) use the `json=` parameter to avoid `headers={...`. I will update my answer to include this.